# Number of zero elements in a vector

Tags: probability, combinatorics, vectors

Define a vector $v=(v_1,...,v_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2^{\alpha}}$ (i.e. the elements are $\alpha$-bit length).

**My question:** What is the expected number of components of the vector $v$ that are zero?

**My approach:** The probability of an element of the vector to be zero is exactly $\frac{1}{2^{\alpha}}$. How to continue from this point?

By the way, I suspect the answer is $\frac{n}{2^{\alpha}}$. But, I need a formal proof.

Comment: This all depends on the (unspecified) probability distribution ... But if all bits are determined by fair coin tossing, and are independent at least within each component, then indedd the probability of a component to be zero is $\frac1{2^\alpha}$. So the expected number of zero components in the $i$th component is $\frac1{2^\alpha}$. The expected number for the total count then is the sum of the expected values (even if the components are *not* independent), so indeed we arrive at $\frac n{2^\alpha}$

Comment: It is about uniform distribution and independent sampling of the elements $v_i$.

Comment: Ok, great @Hagen, it does make sense, you could move to the answer section.